# Laravel query builder not replacing question mark

Tags: laravel

I'm running the following query:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'company')
    ->whereNotIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->from('tasks')->join('projects', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project')
                    ->where('projects.status', '=', Project::STATUS_ARCHIVED);
            })
            ->select('tasks.id');
    });
```

But if I output the whole raw query I get the following:

```
select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`company` = 1 and `id` not in (select `tasks`.`id` from `tasks` inner join `projects` on `projects`.`id` = `tasks`.`project` and `projects`.`status` = ?)
```

As you can see at the end of the raw query there's a question mark that wasn't replaced with the actual value, instead `'tasks'.'company' = 1` was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue by manually setting the bindings using

```
->setBindings([Project::STATUS_ARCHIVED]);
```

Here's the whole snippet:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'company')
    ->whereNotIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->from('tasks')->join('projects', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project')
                    ->where('projects.status', '=', '?');
            })
            ->select('tasks.id')
            ->setBindings([Project::STATUS_ARCHIVED]);
    })
    ->where('status', '=', Task::STATUS_INCOMPLETE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `illuminate.query` event. Before the query add the following event listener:

```php
use Event;

Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $params, $time)
{
    dd([
        $query,  // prepared statement
        $params, // query params (? symbols will be replaced with)
        $time    // execution time
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean but the actual query was displayed by a whoops exception caused by a SQL syntax error complaining about that question mark. I just copied the SQL raw query returned by the error and replaced the question mark with the actual value and then i manually run the query using Sequel Pro.

Comment: did it work correctly when you replaced ``?`` with actual value and manually run the query?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `->get();` to the end of the query.

Try:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'company')
    ->whereNotIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->from('tasks')->join('projects', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project')
                    ->where('projects.status', '=', Project::STATUS_ARCHIVED);
            })
            ->select('tasks.id');
    })->get();
```