# Laravel binding replace question mark from variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have area table like :

```
-----------------------------
id | name        | level
-----------------------------
1  | India       | country
2  | Some?thing  | country
```

in this table i have added a row with **question mark** and i want to select that row as follow
Query in eloquent :

```
Area::select(*)->where("name","LIKE", "%Some?thing%")
               ->where("level","=","country")->get();
```

but this not give the result because question mark in string in where condition replaced with bindings

the raw sql generated is :

```
select * from area where name like %Somecountrything% AND level = ?
```

but i want it like

```
select * from area where name like %Some?thing% AND level = country
```

Comment: try something like this `whereRaw("name LIKE %Some?thing%")`

Comment: I have tried with this but it didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/29388450/1318946

Comment: I really do not know if it can work, but try to escape the question mark with a slash. \?

Comment: @Arjun: check my answer in my comment I forget to give single quote, and I have tested my answer it is generating the correct output.

Comment: Area::where("name","LIKE", "%Some?thing%")
               ->where("level","=","country")->get(); is working for me

Comment: @Muthu17 have you see the raw sql? this is not giving result in my code.

Comment: echo MyModel::where("name","LIKE", "%Some?thing%")->get(); I have tested like this, But Its working fine for me. Even you can use whereRaw also. echo MyModel::whereRaw("name LIKE '%Some?thing%'")->get()

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Area::whereRaw("name LIKE '%Some?thing%'")
               ->where("level","=","country")->get();
```

You can inject raw mysql queries to laravel with the help of `whereRaw()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereRaw()` for this

like

```
DB::table('users')->whereRaw("email LIKE '%Some?thing%'")->get();
Print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```

It output like this:

```
select * from `abc_users` where email LIKE '%Some?thing%'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! but this creates problems when i add another where condition to this.

Comment: what problem? you can add multiple `where()`.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
Area::select('*') ....
```

Full Code:

```
Client::select('*')->where("name","LIKE", "%xyz?xyz%")
               ->where("city","=","331")->get();
```

Output:
[image]